# Map in HttpClient api

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular4.
How would I modify the following code, when moving from `@angular/http` `Http` to `HttpClient` (https://angular.io/guide/http) ?

```
let observable: Observable<User[]> =
  this.http.get(uri)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json()._embedded['users'])
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

The JSON returned by the get has the following form

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "doe_jo",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "john@doe.com",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/api/users/doe_jo"
          },
          "user": {
            "href": "http://localhost/api/users/doe_jo"
          }
        }
      }, ...
```

Especially the map part I can not translate to the HttpClient api

```
.map((response: Response) => response.json()._embedded['users'])
```

I guess I have to do something like following, but cant figure out, 
how exactly to do this. Here the `?` stands for the JSON type, returned by the request.

```
let observable: Observable<User[]> =
  this.http.get<?>(uri)
    .map((myjson: ?) => myjson._embedded['users'])
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Template

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let user of users | async">
  <td style="text-align: left; width:10%">{{user.id}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: left; width:20%">{{user.name}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: left; width:70%">{{user.email}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: you have to do it inside subscribe(). this.http.get(uri).subscribe((myjson: ?) => {let user =  myjson._embedded['users']})

Comment: But I need the Observable, to use it for `ngFor`

Comment: see the updated comment

Comment: can you post the template code as well

Comment: posted the template

Comment: The code that you've tried looks perfectly fine (besides the question mark). Is there any error in the console?

Comment: post me where you assign the response to users object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main practical difference between `Http` and `HttpClient` is that `res.json()` and other `res` methods aren't needed (`responseType` option is used in `HttpClient` instead and it defaults to `json`).

This works best when there is separate `.map((response: Response) => response.json())` operator.

Considering that there is:

```
let observable: Observable<User[]> = this.http.get(uri)
.map((response: Response) => response.json())
.map((json: { _embedded: { users: User[] } }) => json._embedded.users));
```

It will be:

```
let observable: Observable<User[]> = this.httpClient.get<{ _embedded: { users: User[] } }>(uri)
.map((json) => json._embedded.users));
.catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

`map()` is called on an Observable if you want to change the oncoming stream of data before you `subscribe` to it. What you are doing seems right in the first chunk of code you posted. However, you have yet to subscribe to the observable. You could either subscribe to it or you could `.toPromise()` after the response and promisify it.

```
httpGet()
.map((response) => return changes made to http response)
.toPromise()
.then((response) => {
   this.users = response;
})
```

And then in the html, I'd

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
```

Comment: Thanks. Check the answer of esthus. His version allows to return the Observalbe directly, without explicitely change to the data. In the template you then have to use `async`.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, remove the `.json` , from the map response, because what is actually `HttpClient` is doing, is receiving back the information as json, even if you don't specify that it might fix your problem without making other changes.

Thanks